# Django - Filtering prefetch_related

Tags: python, sql, django

I am having trouble with filtering one of my views. It is a DetailView, that also display lots of additional tables.
I have my models as such:

```
 class Pipeline(models.Model):

 class Stage(models.Model):
     pipeline = models.ForeignKey(Pipeline, related_name='stages')

 class Opportunity(models.Model):
     status = ....
     stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage, related_name='opportunities')

 class EstateActivity(models.Model):
      time = models.DateTimeField(...)
      opportunity = models.ForeignKey(EstateOpportunity, related_name='activities')
```

Now, I am displaying Pipeline DetailView. In this DetailView I use prefetch related on all these models

```
qs.filter(users=self.request.user).prefetch_related('stages__opportunities__activities')
```

One pipeline contains many stages, and each stage containst many opportunities etc.
However, I need to filter out firstly opportunities by their status(which can be obtained from URL). And to each opportunity I need to filter one specific activity (most recent activity and if such doesn't exist, then most recent from the past). So far, I tried using extra, however this doesn't work. I fail to come up with a solution that doesn't involve hitting database each time. Also, I can't just select it each model one by one

```
context['opportunities'] = Opportunity.objects.filter(user=..., ..pipeline=self.object, status=.....)
```

because I need to have the relations with Stage for template. If I just iterate over context['opportunities'] and add the desired Activity to each one, it's gonna hit database each time. Sadly, the prefetch_related filtering is only in the development version, with stable release in about 5 months.

Answer (score 0):

Would [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) work for you instead?

```
qs.filter(users=self.request.user).select_related('stages')
```

Alternatively, work backwards:

```
opportunities = EstateActivity.objects.filter(opportunity__stage__pipeline__users=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Hi, unfourtunately, select_related doesn't work for these backward relations, as it hits the database each time, the same as if there were no such thing. Also, the backward thing wont work for me too, I explained it in the last paragraph, and wrote almost the same line as you, because I need to have opportunities related to Stage, and to each Opportunity have related Activity. Otherwise I have to iterate over the Opportunities in every Stage in template and check if opportunity.stage_id == stage.id which is very inefficient. The same would go for Activities under Opportunity.

Comment: Then I guess you could query each Model for the set of rows that you're interested in (much like NoSQL).  Or you can drop in the code that's in development and help them debug it.